# What VisualState Name should I use for styling the ToggleSplitButton in WinUI 3.0 for when the control is disabled?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I've copied the style for the SplitButton, but it lacks any VisualState's named "Disabled" or "CheckedDisabled".  I've added these manually but the don't seem to have any effect in my app.  When I try added a VisualState named "PrimaryDisabled" I get an exception (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException) -- which I don't get with the Disabled/CheckedDisabled visual states.  Below is an example of the VisualState I have implemented for "Disabled"

```
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryBackgroundGrid.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryBackgroundGrid.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                    <Setter Target="PrimaryBackgroundGrid.Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AdbsButtonDisabledColor}" />
                                    <Setter Target="SecondaryBackgroundGrid.Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AdbsButtonDisabledColor}" />

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
```

The same VisualState works as expected with my custom Style for the ToggleButton. Both have the same binding for their respective IsEnabled properties.  Both get disabled at the same time (neither are clickable) only the ToggleSplitButton is not displaying the same color despite have the same VisualState properties in its style.

WinUI 3.0 (Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK.1.1.3)

I would appreciate any suggestions/solutions anybody has to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ToggleSplitButton uses the SplitButtonStyle and it does have a visual state for Disabled. Copy the style from this link and make your changes.

[SplitButtonStyle](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/SplitButton/SplitButton_rs1_v1.xaml)

Comment: I used the SplitButtonStyle as my template, and yes it does have a visual state for Disabled.  I modified mine as above, and the style for the Background isn't being applied.    A lot of the states distinguish between Primary and Secondary, so I also tried adding visual states for PrimaryDisabled and SecondaryDisabled, but that causes errors when trying to run the app.

Comment: But I do thank you for correcting my incorrect statement that there is no visual state for Disabled.  :+